# $\delta - \alpha$ is unbounded in $\delta$

Tags: set-theory

I am trying to understand better an example of unbounded sets in set theory.

> Let $\delta$ be a limit ordinal. Then a set $A \subseteq \delta$ is unbounded in $\delta$, if $supA = \delta$.

Then for any $\alpha < \delta$, $\delta - \alpha$ is unbounded in $\delta$.

I realize it should be easy, but I can't deduce it myself. I would appreciate if someone could walk me through it.

**EDIT:** I think, I understood what made me confused. If I am correct now, then $\delta - \alpha$ is a normal set subtraction: everything that is in set $\delta$, but is not in a set $\alpha$.

Then let $\gamma \in \delta$. Either $\gamma < \alpha$, then there is $\alpha \in \delta - \alpha$ and $\gamma \leq \alpha$.

Or $\gamma \geq \alpha$, then $\gamma \in \delta - \alpha$ and $\gamma \leq \gamma$.

Could anyone please point out if I am not correct?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you prove it in the case $\delta = \omega$, for example? What about $\delta = \omega^2$? Doing some examples like that can help a lot to get a bit of intuition. It would make it easier to write a good answer for you if you write a little about that, and either where you get stuck with that or where you get stuck with translating the ideas from there to the general case.

Comment: An equivalent definition that might be easier to use is that $A\subseteq \delta$ is unbounded in a limit ordinal $\delta$ if for all $\gamma\in A$ there is an $\eta\in A$ with $\eta>\gamma.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen pardon me if you saw my last comment - I'm losing my marbles. I think your definition should say "for all $\gamma \in \delta$". (but I agree that it's a nicer definition!)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen nope you’re not losing your marbles. It should say for all $\gamma\in \delta$ instead of for all $\gamma\in A$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Hello, thank you for your advice. I have edited my question, could you please take a look?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Hello, thank you for an equivalent definition. I have edited my question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: I think you've got the idea now - it looks right to me :). (So long as you believe that it follows from what you've written that $\sup A = \delta$). Indeed it does have to be set subtraction - if it was (left) ordinal subtraction then it wouldn't be true.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thanks a lot!